# Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') in np.bincount

Tags: python, numpy

Unfortunately I cannot share the data I am now using, so this question will not contain an MWE.

I have this code:

```py
def baseline(labels):
    # dummy classifier returning the most common label in labels
    print(labels.shape)
    print(type(labels))
    print(type(labels[0]))
    print(type(labels[2]))
    print(labels)
    counts = np.bincount(labels)
    value = np.argmax(counts)
```

This code runs fine with most input files containing the `labels`. However, on a subset of files, I get the error:

**Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'**

that I cannot understand. Output is:

```py
(891,)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
[0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "07_training_test.py", line 577, in <module>
    fire.Fire(main)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 141, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 466, in _Fire
    component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace(
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 681, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "07_training_test.py", line 554, in main
    res = process_file(fn, parameters, config)
  File "07_training_test.py", line 434, in process_file
    value_train, train_acc = utils.baseline(full_labels.loc[train_i].to_numpy())
  File "/home/user/workspace/proj/src/pipeline_paper/utils.py", line 186, in baseline
    counts = np.bincount(labels)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in bincount
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

There are other questions on this error, but in different contexts so I was not able to solve the issue following the answers.

Comment: If `type(labels[0])` is `<class 'int'>`, then clearly `labels.dtype` is `object`. With numpy arrays, `dtype=object` means that you are using the array as a list of references instead of an actual densely packed array.

Comment: You need to re-evaluate how your `labels` are created. Since the information is not presented here, I can tell you that the error is expected, but not how to fix it.

Comment: Not down-voting because you clearly put some effort into providing the information you thought was relevant, but voting to close because it's not.

Comment: `labels.dtype` is the relevant thing to check, not the `type` of a few terms.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know this is not the ideal question. Forgive me, I cannot rshare the data.

Comment: @MadPhysicist This comment made me understand the root cause of the error. So now the code runs fine without the cast in the accepted answer. Thank you. However, such "references" were read from a pickle file: I had this error only in Python scripts, in a Jupyter notebook the same files causing the error were ok.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to help future readers, and not just solve your immediate issue. You don't need to share your data, just a couple of lines of code simulating how it was created would be sufficient.

Comment: Gotcha. How did you end up fixing the problem?

Comment: These files represent folds in a k-fold cross-validation, with a training and a test set. The files without the error were created starting from separate training and test dataframes. I added the column "label" to each them, concatenated vertically and saved. The files causing the problem did not originate from separate training and test dataframes. I had a single dataframe X and two sets of indexes train_idx, test_idx. In order to add labels I did X.loc[train_idx, "label"] = labels (same for test). This caused the error. (not enough space for better replies sorry).

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was not able to replicate the issue (as the author of the accepted answer). Actually, as I said, I was able to compute `baseline` in a Jupyter notebook (using the same conda environment as the scripts raising the error).

Comment: Sounds like a library version issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can reproduce your error:

```py
>>> arr = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=891)
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('int64')

>>> baseline(arr)  # Works fine
>>> arr = arr.astype(object)
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('O')
>>> baseline(arr)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

So even if your array contains integers but has a type "object", `np.bincount` throws the error. Try to cast `labels` to numpy integer array manually before running the code. E.g.:

```py
arr = arr.astype(np.int8)
```

Comment: This sounds like a workaround to the real solution of not creating an incorrectly-typed array in the first place.